# Creating Multiple Scatter Line Graphs using a Loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, graph

Any help I can get here is really appreciated! I'm new to VBA and have been struggling with this coding for a while whilst not getting very far.

I'm trying to create a macro in excel which will create multiple scatter line graphs for separate ranges of data.

After a lot of learning as I go, I've come up with the following code:

```
Sub CreateChart()

' Prepare coordinates for placing the graph in GW Charts Sheet
Dim y As Integer
y = 0
Dim x As Integer
x = 0

' Prepare chart series names
Dim name1 As String
Dim name2 As String

' Select the Gross Weight Worksheet
Sheets("GW").Select

' Select chart type to create
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

' Set chart dimensions
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 7").IncrementLeft 1204.4118110236
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 7").IncrementTop 190.5881889764

' Format Y Axis Units
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

' Format X Axis Units
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 1
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 10
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 1
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

' Set X Axis Title
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Year & Quarter"

' Set Y Axis Title
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Gross Weight (Metric Tonnes)"

' Prepare for loop by creating variables
Dim w As Integer
w = 4
Dim z As Integer
z = 5
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1

'This bit needs looping

Do Until counter = 90

    ' Set chart series names
    name1 = (Range("B" & w).Value) & (" ") & ("In")
    name2 = (Range("B" & z).Value) & (" ") & ("Out")

    ' Set name of series one (GW In)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = name1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = (Range("E" & w, "N" & w))

    ' Set name of series two (GW Out)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = name2
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = (Range("E" & z, "N" & z))

    ' Set Chart Title
    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = (Range("C" & w))

    ' Move chart into GW Charts sheet
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="GW Charts"

    ' Position chart on GW Charts sheet
    With ActiveChart
    .Parent.Top = y
    .Parent.Left = x
    End With

    w = w + 2
    z = z + 2
    y = y + 200
    counter = counter + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

What I now need to do is find a way for the loop to work, so that it can create multiple graphs by:

- increasing the w and z values by 2 each to select the next required data
- increasing the y value by 200 so the graphs are added to the "GW Charts" sheet nicely underneath each other

Sorry for the long question, it's taken me a long time just to write the code to produce 1 correct graph, I'm now completely stuck on how to loop it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please be aware that questions should be narrowly targeted, otherwise you run the danger of a question being marked "too broard". Good work on your code so far. To help you extend it, however, you need to explain where the additional series, chart title, etc. should come from. Making a loop is simple enough, but getting the loop to do something useful requires knowing, in addition: how should the loop know when to stop? You can use the [edit] link below the question to describe how your workbook is set up to provide the information necessary to create additional charts.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that now :)

Comment: I think I might have it! I've got my loop in the wrong place, meaning that I'm simply creating the same graph over and over again. Attempting to fix now, will then answer my own question if successful.

Answer (score 0):

Success!

I've now created the following code which works perfectly!

```
Sub CreateChart()

' Select an empty cell to prevent error
Range("P1").Select

' Turn screen updating off so hopefully this whole thing doesn't crash and burn
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Prepare coordinates for placing the graph in GW Charts Sheet
Dim y As Integer
y = 0
Dim x As Integer
x = 0

' Prepare for loop by creating variables
Dim w As Integer
w = 4
Dim z As Integer
z = 5
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1

' Enter the loop
Do Until counter = 82

    ' Prepare chart series names
    Dim name1 As String
    Dim name2 As String

    ' Select the Gross Weight Worksheet
    Sheets("GW").Select

    ' Select chart type to create
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    ' Set chart dimensions
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 7").IncrementLeft 1204.4118110236
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 7").IncrementTop 190.5881889764

    ' Format Y Axis Units
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    ' Format X Axis Units
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 10
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 1
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    ' Set X Axis Title
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Year & Quarter"

    ' Set Y Axis Title
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Gross Weight (Metric Tonnes)"

    ' Set chart series names
    name1 = (Range("B" & w).Value) & (" ") & ("In")
    name2 = (Range("B" & z).Value) & (" ") & ("Out")

    ' Set name of series one (GW In)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = name1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = (Range("E" & w, "N" & w))

    ' Set name of series two (GW Out)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = name2
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = (Range("E" & z, "N" & z))

    ' Set Chart Title
    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = (Range("C" & w))

    ' Move chart into GW Charts sheet
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="GW Charts"

    ' Position chart on GW Charts sheet
    With ActiveChart
    .Parent.Top = y
    .Parent.Left = x
    End With

    w = w + 2
    z = z + 2
    y = y + 250
    counter = counter + 1

Loop

' Turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Display a friendly message box
MsgBox "Graphing Complete :)"

End Sub
```

My problem was the placing of the loop in the code. Hopefully this helps anybody who encounters a similar problem.

Simply change +2 on the the W and Z variables to capture more/less rows at once :)